# $n$-volume of a ball is proportional to the $n$-th power of the unit $n$-volume

Tags: volume, spheres

I am searching for a paper wich demonstrates this proposition so I can reference it in an essay I'm currently working on. In mathematical notation, the proposition looks something like this:

$$V_n(r)=\alpha r^n \quad, \quad \alpha = V_n(1)$$

I've been digging arround internet, but the best I could find was the proof wich the Wikipedia page offers and our techer told us that we couldn't refer to any Wikipedia page. Can someone help, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is simply a result of a property of determinants. Suppose you have
a subset $A\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ whose volume is, say, $\alpha$. Given $r>0$,  what is the volume of the set $rA$? Since $rA$ is obtained from $A$ by applying the linear transformation $Tx= rx$, we have
$$V(rA)=V(TA)=|\det T|V(A)=r^nV(A)=r^n\alpha$$

So if you need a reference, just open any linear algebra book and look for the volume formula of determinants.